# How to run multiple threads together in simpler code in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, concurrency, python-multithreading

I'm trying to simplify the code of threads below:

```py
import threading

def test1():
    print("test1")

def test2():
    print('test2')

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=test1)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=test2)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```

So, I want to simplify this part of code below to:

```py
# ...

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=test1)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=test2)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```

Something like one line of code below:

```py
# ...

threading.Threads(test1, test2).start().join()
```

Are there any ways to do this? and it's ok if it's not one line of code as long as it's simpler.

Comment: Why do you need it to be a one liner? Simpler how? less typing?

Comment: @wwii. It's just messy. Don't you think so?

Comment: iterate over a list of targets?

Answer (score 2):

just write it yourself ...

```py
class Threads:
    def __init__(self,*functions):
        self._functions = functions
        self._threads = []

    def start(self):
        for func in self._functions:
            thread = threading.Thread(target=func)
            self._threads.append(thread)
            thread.start()
        return self

    def join(self):
        for thread in self._threads:
            thread.join()
```

usage:

```py
Threads(test1, test2).start().join()
```

**Edit**: using threadpool is more pythonic

```py
from operator import methodcaller
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

caller = methodcaller("__call__")
with ThreadPool() as pool:
     results = pool.map(caller, [test1, test2])
```

Comment: Your "threadpool" way works properly. This is pythonic. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import threading

threads_list = []
for i in range(thread_count)
    thread = threading.Thread(target=target_func, args=(args,))
    thread.start()
    threads_list.append(thread)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor the functions so that they are the same function but with different inputs, e.g.

```
def test(s):
    print(s)
```

Then, you can use higher level `ThreadPool` api. This calls the `test` function with each of the elements in the list `['test1', 'test2']` via different threads. So you don't need to manage details such as starting or joining the threads.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

with ThreadPool as pool:
     results = pool.map(test, ['test1', 'test2'])
```